# Sql strictly more than query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm in `PostgreSQL`.

I need to print all mailing with creation date strictly more that `2015-04-04`. I tried the following queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM mailing.mailing 
WHERE creation_date > '2015-04-04';
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM mailing.mailing 
WHERE creation_date >= '2015-04-04';
```

But they produced the same result set(including '2015-04-04'). Is it possible to write such a query without explicitly saying     `WHERE creation_date >= '2015-04-05';`

UPD: The column's type is `timestamp without time zone`.

Comment: Is the data type for the creation_date column DATE or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: @jarlh Yeah, timestamp without time zone

Answer (score 3):

If your `creation_date` field is of type `datetime`
try comparing it to `'2015-04-04 23:59:59'` instead, 
as `'2015-04-04 08:30:00'` seems to be greater than `'2015-04-04'`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your default date format for your database is `'YYYY-MM-DD'` and `creation_date` field is a date type, your query will actually be converted automatically to something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mailing.mailing 
WHERE creation_date > to_date('2015-04-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

The date value you have provided represents the first second of that day, that's why you see no difference between your queries. (Your first query would exclude the first second of the day though.)

What you could do to avoid this is:

```
where creation_date >= to_date('2015-04-05 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

or

```
where date_trunc(creation_date-1) = '2015-04-04'
```